# Duplicate columns with Pandas merge?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, duplicates

I have a data frame `a`:

```
ID    value1
1     nan
2     nan
3     nan
4     nan
5     nan
```

and then two other data frames, `b` and `c`:

```
ID     value1
2      20
3      10

ID     value1
1      58
4      20
```

When I do `a.merge(b, on='ID').merge(c, on='ID')`, I get duplicate columns of `value`. My end result has the columns:

```
ID     value1_x    value1_y    value1
```

but I want to end up with:

```
ID    value1
1     58
2     20
3     10
4     20
5     nan
```

How do I use `b` and `c` to populate the values in `a` without duplicate columns?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) old column `value1` in `a`:

```
df1 = pd.concat([b,c])
print (df1)
   ID  value1
0   2      20
1   3      10
0   1      58
1   4      20

df2 = pd.merge(a ,df1, on='ID', how='left', suffixes=('_',''))
df2.drop('value1_', axis=1, inplace=True)
print (df2)
   ID  value1
0   1    58.0
1   2    20.0
2   3    10.0
3   4    20.0
4   5     NaN
```

Comment: I'm going to update the OP, but let's say `a` has ID's 5-10 that are also nans in `value1` - and I want to keep them as nans.

Comment: Please see update, solution is very similar - only added `suffixes` for adding `_` to first column and empty string to second column.

Comment: what if I want to do the same thing but drop many duplicates columns because I have a ton of columns in the dataset?